# Electron framework - Can I select what version of node.js to use?

Tags: frameworks, electron, desktop-application

I am new to Electron.

One of the biggest benefits of Electron is considered that it always comes with the latest versions of Node.js and Chromium.

But can I select which version of node js to use ?

Comment: "One of the biggest benefits of Electron is considered that it always comes with the latest versions of Node.js and Chromium." where have you read that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't select which version of Node to use, however you can upgrade Node version as long as it is compatible with the current Electron's Chromium version.

Check this for farther information: https://electronjs.org/docs/development/upgrading-node